# How to increase the number of vertices in the given graph structure

Tags: graphics, graphs

I have the following code :

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\foreach \n in {1,...,16}
  \fill (90-\n*22.5:2cm) coordinate (v\n) circle[radius=.5mm] 
    ++(90-\n*22.5:10pt) node {\n};
\foreach \m/\n in {1/2,1/3,1/4,1/5,1/6,1/7,1/8,1/9,1/10,1/11,1/12,1/13,1/14,1/15,1/16}
  \draw (v\n)--(v\m);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

The code works really well for 16 vertices.
But now I want to double the number of vertices.
I want to make the number of vertices 32.
Unfortunately the vertices start overlapping if its increased beyond 16.

Is there any way to fix it and increase the number of vertices but to retain the overall shape of the structure?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code does not work because your loop is considering `(360/16) = 22.5` degrees in `(90-\n*22.5:2cm)` and `(90-\n*22.5:10pt)`. If you want to get something more flexible, you should do something like `360/n`, with `n` as an arbitrary number.

PGF/TikZ offers you `\pgfmathsetmacro` which allows you, roughly speaking, to do math calculator evaluations, so you can divide and multiply according to the pattern required. Another remark is enclosing commands to be repeated with braces in case you need to specify two or more of them:

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\newcommand{\MyLines}[1]{%
\begin{tikzpicture}
%Note N is arbitrary
\foreach \n in {1,...,#1}
%\Division is, well, what its name means
%Note \Division is part of the loop so multiplying by \n is possible
{\pgfmathsetmacro\Division{360/#1}
%These values pass through 360/n to 360
\pgfmathsetmacro\Divisions{(360*\n)/#1}
\fill (90-\Divisions:2cm) coordinate (v\n) circle[radius=.5mm] 
++(90-\Divisions:10pt) node {\n};}
\foreach \n in {1,...,#1}
{\draw (v\n)--(v1);}
\end{tikzpicture}
}
\begin{document}
\MyLines{32}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Play with other values and see the results.

### EDIT

If you actually want to see it in a document, here's an example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[paperwidth=9cm,paperheight=9cm,margin=1em]{geometry}
\usepackage[spanish]{babel} %Proud of my mother tongue
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsthm}
\pgfdeclarelayer{nice}   
\pgfsetlayers{nice,main} 
\newcommand{\MyLines}[1]{%
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    %Note N is arbitrary
    \foreach \n in {1,...,#1}
    %\Division is, well, what its name means
    %Note \Division is part of the loop so multiplying by \n is possible
    {\pgfmathsetmacro\Division{360/#1}
        %These values pass through 360/n to 360
        \pgfmathsetmacro\Divisions{(360*\n)/#1}
        \draw[fill=white] (90-\Divisions:3cm) coordinate (v\n) circle[radius=.7em] node {\n};}
%       ++(90-\Divisions:10pt) node {\n};}
    \begin{pgfonlayer}{nice}
    \foreach \n in {1,...,#1}
    {\draw (v\n)--(v1);}
    \end{pgfonlayer}
    \end{tikzpicture}
}
\begin{document}
\begin{proof}
Hola
\begin{center}
\MyLines{32}
\end{center}
\end{proof}
\end{document}
```

A recommendation to you: [PGF/TikZ documentation.](https://ctan.org/pkg/pgf?lang=en)
[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer'

Comment: Can I ask you another question? Is it possible to write the numbers 1,2,3...32 inside a node rather than below the node?

Comment: I want to put the number say 1 inside the node rather than writing 1 below the circle of radius 0.5. Is it possible to write? Please help

Comment: Also how can I put the entire command inside a document? I want to put this in a document under `\begin{proof} .........\end{proof}`. How to put it?

Comment: Mmm... You should 1) make it another question, or 2) make a more specific questions the next time.

Comment: I updated my answer. If that doesn't answer to your now more specific question, I'm done.

Comment: Thanks a lot, Can you do only one more thing? Can you just put your first answer in which the nodes were represented by dots in `\begin{proof}...\end{proof}`

Comment: Its the last request I have, please put your first code in `\begin{proof}` thats all